# Native table 'performance_schema'.'???' has the wrong structure

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following:

```
Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_instances' has the wrong structure
Native table 'performance_schema'.'cond_instances' has the wrong structure
Native table 'performance_schema'.'rwlock_instances' has the wrong structure
Native table 'performance_schema'.'mutex_instances' has the wrong structure
...
```

And on it goes
These errors come up when I restart MySql. It seems to cause MySql Administrator to become unstable, I get a lot of:

```
"MySQL server has gone away"
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Apparently MySQL schema storage is broken due to a reason. These reasons may be:

- You have broken the database `information_schema`
- File system corrupted or some bugs in the file system damaged the database.
- MySQL internals broke the schema database due to a bug in MySQL (maybe nobody encountered it before).

If you don't have backups however you are still able to access your data, first backup your data then do the following:

If you have backups, then reinstall MySQL (before that completely clear all data of mysql) and then import your data.

Comment: It was innodb tried a number of times to reinstall, didn't work. In the end I had to reinstall as a non-transactional database (disabling innodb I believe) and that fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Instead of reinstallation first check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20262826/2166188 . @Musa's answer worked for me.

Comment: This answer needs to be deleted.

Comment: right solution is what @Musa updated in his post....this may be fine with small data size but what about if db size is more than 500 GB.

Comment: This answer is the extreme path, while Musa's answer proved effective for many (including me) and, being faster and easier to apply, should be tried before proceeding with a database replacement.

Answer (score 250):

Try following command in shell (the root user here is the mysql root user, not the system root)

```
sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -p

sudo service mysql restart
```

Make sure to **restart mysql** after running this (All credit to @Mikepote in the comments.)

Comment: Yeah, upgrade to the newer version without mysql_upgrade may cause the wrong structure error

Comment: If anyone still has this error *after running mysql_upgrade* try restarting the mysql service. This fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks, Mikepote, that's exactly the problem I had. I ran mysql_upgrade, then got this error, and realized after reading your comment that I hadn't restarted mysql.

Comment: I was upgrade to 5.7.10 on Ubuntu 15.04 and it required a restart of the machine for that error to disappear from MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Worked for me as well on two debian based machines, though I had to use the `--force` switch as it was no mysql fault in my case.

Comment: I copy data from 5.5 to 5.6 (portable version on Windows 64bit) and get same errors but still can use db correctly for a while. However, this answer also works for me to eliminate those errors in errlog. Thanks!

Comment: I was getting this error in my docker-compose based container. Just did `docker exec -it mysql-container-id bash`  and `mysql_upgrade -u root -p`  and it fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Using homebrew: `brew services restart mysql@5.7` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 24):

Im my case it appeared when specific query was run on a table.

And log also contained:

> Missing system table mysql.proxies_priv; please run mysql_upgrade to
>   create it

I've run **mysql_upgrade** and after that problem has gone.

Comment: As above, you have to restart the server after running mysql_upgrade.  Until you do, you will continue to see these errors.

Answer (score 19):

I had this problem, the answer was here by @Berend de Boer

Restart mysql after the upgrade.

[[ERROR]Native table performance schema has the wrong structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000911/errornative-table-performance-schema-has-the-wrong-structure)

Answer (score 8):

This error is encountered when you installed MySQL over a previous installation that was configured without the Performance Schema or an older version of Performance schema that may not have all the current tables.

I also encountered this issue on [mamp](/questions/tagged/mamp). To resolve it, I have executed the following:

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/
sudo ./upgradeMysql.sh
```

Remember to restart the mysql server.

You can read the [Performance Schema Build Configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema-build-configuration.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

If the database is a Akonadi (KDE) database the above won't be enough.
You need to mirror the options given to your mysqld, check with

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

Copy the options to the mysql_upgrade commands (I did not need '-u root -p' but you might)

```
mysql_upgrade --defaults-file=/home/USER/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf --datadir=/home/USER/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/ --socket=/tmp/akonadi-USER.x0Bvxr/mysql.socket
```

I really think the --socket option is the key.

Comment: What is it? Never heard of it! @@

Comment: It will be required only if running multiple mysql services on same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mysql_upgrade` and then restart mysql and its working back

Answer (score 0):

It seems this happens after you have done upgrade. Simply restart mysql:

Like run below command in CMD

```
sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -p

service mysql restart
```

and the error should now have disappeared.