# [ERROR]Native table performance schema has the wrong structure

Tags: mysql, structure

```
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_current' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history_long' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_consumers' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_instruments' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_timers' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'performance_timers' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'threads' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'mutex_instances' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'rwlock_instances' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'cond_instances' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_instances' has the wrong structure
150814  9:09:14 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.44-cll-lve'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Atomicorp
```

Then I run

```
mysql_upgrade
```

It shows:

Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql

Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck

FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

Answer (score 67):

It seems this happens after you have done upgrade. Simply restart mysql:

```
service mysql restart
```

and the error should now have disappeared.

Comment: This worked for me after upgrading to mysql 5.7.12. MySql seemed to be working fine, but I couldn't do a `mysqldump`. After restart it worked.

Comment: I concur. This worked for me after updating MySQL to 5.7 (from a Ubuntu release update from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS.) This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Also work for me. Same problem. Upgrade 14.01 to 16.04 Ubuntu, fail Mysql process. Several problems ans this last problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me as well, upgraded Plesk MySQL 5.5 to 5.7

Comment: Yep start the mysql server after the upgrade fixes it.

Comment: I had to do `systemctl restart mysqld` instead in my CentoS 7.

Answer (score 11):

If you're running MySQL on your local device, you need to upgrade your mysql and then restart:

Upgrade:

```
$ mysql_upgrade -u root
```

Restart:

```
$ mysql.server restart
```

Comment: Thanks; restarting mysql is a necessary step.

Answer (score 0):

Windows7 Pro, Mysql 5.7, Java Tomcat

I attempted to update the mysql server from version 5.7.8 to version 5.7.18 using the Windows web updater available on Mysql.com. The new version installed, started as a service, but wouldn't serve anything including log in.

1. Using the Windows command box, change directory to C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin
2. Type: mysql_upgrade --force -u root -p
3. Enter the password of the previous version that is being upgraded.
4. Restart the Mysql service at Windows > Start > Administrative Tools > Services

The Mysql server immediately started and connected to the Java Servlet container.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me when I upgraded MySQL in MAMP Server.
All I had to do was restart the server.
I clicked the button "Stop Server" and then "Start Server".
Everything was fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading MySQL from 5.6 to 5.7, I got this similar error message:

```
Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_variables' has the wrong structure
```

I was running MySQL in a Docker container and I got rid of the error message by restarting the container with this:

```
docker-compose down && docker-compose up
```

Answer (score -1):

Same problem here

```
$ mysqldump -h localhost --lock-all-tables --set-gtid-purged=OFF -u root -p --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --all-databases > dump.sql
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ndbinfo\_version'': Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_variables' has the wrong structure (1682)
```

Have you test a

```
$ mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

or

```
$ mysql_upgrade --force -u root -p
```

Comment: this doesn't look like a solution to me - is it?

Comment: Running that doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score -2):

mysqldump just add parameter like this:  `--skip-lock-tables`

can avoid this error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ndbinfo\_version'': Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_variables' has the wrong structure (1682)
```

Comment: I thought this was downvoted because it was just avoiding a problem but might still work. Unfortunately, this didn't work when I tried it.

Comment: It doesn't help