# no active checks on server [192.168.100.100:10051]: host [scidb601] not found

Tags: zabbix

The Server zabbix_agentd.conf

Server=127.0.0.1,192.168.100.100

```
### Option: ListenPort
#   Agent will listen on this port for connections from the server.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1024-32767
# Default:
# ListenPort=10050


### Option: ListenIP
#   List of comma delimited IP addresses that the agent should listen on.
#   First IP address is sent to Zabbix server if connecting to it to retrieve list of active checks.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# ListenIP=0.0.0.0

### Option: StartAgents
#   Number of pre-forked instances of zabbix_agentd that process passive checks.
#   If set to 0, disables passive checks and the agent will not listen on any TCP port.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-100
# Default:
 StartAgents=8

##### Active checks related

### Option: ServerActive
#   List of comma delimited IP:port (or hostname:port) pairs of Zabbix servers for active checks.
#   If port is not specified, default port is used.
#   IPv6 addresses must be enclosed in square brackets if port for that host is specified.
#   If port is not specified, square brackets for IPv6 addresses are optional.
#   If this parameter is not specified, active checks are disabled.
#   Example: ServerActive=127.0.0.1:20051,zabbix.domain,[::1]:30051,::1,[12fc::1]
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# ServerActive=

ServerActive=192.168.100.100:10051

### Option: Hostname
#   Unique, case sensitive hostname.
#   Required for active checks and must match hostname as configured on the server.
#   Value is acquired from HostnameItem if undefined.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# Hostname=

Hostname=scidb601
```

The Client zabbix_agentd.conf

```
        Server=192.168.100.100
        ### Option: ListenPort
        #   Agent will listen on this port for connections from the server.
        #
        # Mandatory: no
        # Range: 1024-32767
        # Default:
        # ListenPort=10050
        ### Option: ListenIP
        #   List of comma delimited IP addresses that the agent should listen on.
        #   First IP address is sent to Zabbix server if connecting to it to retrieve list of active checks.
        #
        # Mandatory: no
        # Default:
        # ListenIP=0.0.0.0
        ### Option: StartAgents
        #   Number of pre-forked instances of zabbix_agentd that process passive checks.
        #   If set to 0, disables passive checks and the agent will not listen on any TCP port.
        #
        # Mandatory: no
        # Range: 0-100
        # Default:
        # StartAgents=3
        ##### Active checks related
        ### Option: ServerActive
        #   List of comma delimited IP:port (or hostname:port) pairs of Zabbix servers for active checks.
        #   If port is not specified, default port is used.
        #   IPv6 addresses must be enclosed in square brackets if port for that host is specified.
        #   If port is not specified, square brackets for IPv6 addresses are optional.
        #   If this parameter is not specified, active checks are disabled.
        #   Example: ServerActive=127.0.0.1:20051,zabbix.domain,[::1]:30051,::1,[12fc::1]
        #
        # Mandatory: no
        # Default:
        # ServerActive=
        ServerActive=192.168.100.100
        ### Option: Hostname
        #   Unique, case sensitive hostname.
        #   Required for active checks and must match hostname as configured on the server.
        #   Value is acquired from HostnameItem if undefined.
        #
        # Mandatory: no
        # Default:
        # Hostname=
        Hostname=scidb601

**
```

The zabbix_server.log shows: 
cannot send list of active checks to [192.168.100.96]: host [scidb601] not found

```
And in mysql database, there is a host="scidb601" and user="zabbix".


I can not visit the page which adds a host.
```

[image]

Please help me! Thanks a lot!

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
[root@scidb601 ~]# service mysqld status
mysqld (pid 22917) is running...
```

Mysql error log:

```
150814 20:46:41 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
150814 20:46:41 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
150814 20:46:41 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'mutex_instances' has the wrong structure
150814 20:46:41 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'rwlock_instances' has the wrong structure
150814 20:46:41 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'cond_instances' has the wrong structure
150814 20:46:41 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_instances' has the wrong structure
150814 20:46:41 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.44-cll-lve'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Atomicorp
```

Comment: Did to you add the host to zabbix?

Comment: You might find this question relevant: http://serverfault.com/questions/711048/zabbix-cannot-send-list-of-active-checks/ .

Comment: mysql> use mysql;
Database changed
mysql> select host,user from user;
+-----------+--------+
| host      | user   |
+-----------+--------+
| 127.0.0.1 | root   |
| localhost | root   |
| localhost | zabbix |
| scidb601  | zabbix |
+-----------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
In mysql database, I can find the host="scidb601" and the user="zabbix".

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in your agent configuration file.  Or in the zabbix monitoring profile for the system.

This line is telling the agent to check the server for active checks.

```
ServerActive=192.168.100.100:10051
```

If the monitoring profile does not include any you will get the error message you are seeing for the system.
You want this line instead if you are only doing traditional passive checks.

```
Server=192.168.100.100
```

Which is in the top of your configuration file.

Just comment out the ServerActive line and your issues will be fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried upgrading mysql?

Execute:

```
sudo mysql_upgrade -u [mysqlrootuser] -p
```

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288103/native-table-performance-schema-has-the-wrong-structure) may be useful.