# Rake db:migrate Gem Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I am getting the following error when trying to run `rake db:migrate` with the `mysql2` gem:

> > ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_variables' has the wrong structure: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_database'

I have tried `sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -p`, which upgraded `mysql2` to `0.4.2`, but did *not* solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `--force`:

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p --force
```

and restart your `mysql2` gem.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288103/native-table-performance-schema-has-the-wrong-structure) might help you.