# Recover databases from backed up ibdata + frm files on volume

Tags: mysql, database, server

I've got ~ 30 sites worth of databases data on a volume on my server in the following directory `/mnt/volume0/var/lib/mysql`

The directory contains a 6.2G ibdata1 file and directories containing .frm files for each of the websites.

I'm trying to get dumps of the databases so I can move them to another server, however accessing mysql only shows the default databases (as datadir in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` is set to `/var/lib/mysql`)

I've tried changing the datadir in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` to `/mnt/volume0/var/lib/mysql` but mysql fails to start.

It was complaining about "failed to set datadir" which I fixed by running `chown mysql:mysql mysql/ -R` on `/mnt/volume0/var/lib/mysql` but now it's complaining about `Failed password for root from xxx.xx.xxx.xx port 19192 ssh2`

Any help is greatly appriciated!

Thanks

Comment: The best way is to make a mysql dump. But if you arent able to start your old installation, then its important that you have the same MySQL version in your new installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by replacing the contents of `/var/lib/mysql/` on my local machine with the contents of `/mnt/volume0/var/lib/mysql/` (from the server).

I then encountered an error whilst trying to start `MySQL Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist` which I solved by upgrading MySQL on my local machine and restarting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20262826/8231049

Now I'm able to dump the databases from my local machine :)

Edit: Can't accept my answer before waiting 2 days. Will do then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset your password

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

if you have here an error, then you have a bigger problem

```
mysql --user=root mysql
update user set Password=PASSWORD('your new password') where user='root';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

Comment: Before seeing your answer, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling MySQL.

This has now allowed me to changed datadir (as detailed here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04) to the mysql directory on the volume (/mnt/volume0/var/lib/mysql) but mysql still isn't picking up the databases.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: did you wrote [mysqld] in a line before your datadir setting?