# java.sql.SQLException: Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_variables' has the wrong structure

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, structure

Previously I accidentally dropped 'performance_schema' and 'sys' from DB. I ran `mysql_upgrade -u root -p --force --skip-version-check` in order to recreate those two. They were  successfully recreated. I couldn't restart the MySQL service because I couldn't find MySQL running in Administrative Tools -> Services.

So I think some of the database has broken and now every time I try to run my game server I get this error: `java.sql.SQLException: Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_variables' has the wrong structure`

**What can I do to get it fixed?**

I tried using this thread - [Native table 'performance_schema'.'???' has the wrong structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288103) but no success.

By the way, not sure it's important but I'm on *Windows 10* and using *MySQL Query Browser.*

Comment: Please someone help me!